# Can an unbounded set have a finite open cover?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, compactness

Given $K=[0,\infty)$, can I write $C=\{(-0.5,0.75),(0.25,\infty)\}$ or C={$R$} as open covers for $K$?

This a part of a confusion that I have regarding HBT (Heine-Borel Theorem). The HBT requires that sets are closed and bounded for it to have a finite subcover. If an open cover for $K$ can be written as above, this would mean that a subcover would also be finite. Also $R$ is open and can cover any subset of $R$. A subcover can be the cover itself. So $R$ can represent a finite subcover of $K$ (or any subset of $R$). But this does not fit in with HBT, because HBT requires $K$ to be bounded, which it is not. Can you please help me point out where exactly I am going wrong?

Comment: $\{(-0.5,0.5),(0.5,\infty)\}$ doesn't cover $[0,\infty)$.

Comment: @jjagmath I forgot about $0.5$. I know the question has been answered by members, but for the sake of clarification on your point can you still clarify, does $C = \{(-0.5, 0.75), (0.25, \infty)\}$ cover $[0,\infty)$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are wrong when you claim that the Heine-Borel theorem requires that sets are closed and bounded for it to have a finite subcover. That theorem states that, if a subset of $\Bbb R^n$ is closed and bounded, then *every* cover has a finite subcover. It does *not* say that if a set is unbounded or not closed, then no open cover has a finite subcover.

Comment: Follow up question: Is there an example of a set that is unbounded but no open cover has any finite subcover?
Also, is my assertion that $C=\{(−0.5,0.75),(0.25,∞)\}$ or $C=\{R\}$ covers $[0,\infty)$ correct?
Thanks. Sorry for the noob questions.

Comment: @vicky. Every set has a finite cover: the whole space. A finite cover always has a finite subcover (itself). And yes those are valid examples of open covers of $[0,\infty)$. So for any subspace there are finite open covers and open covers *with* a finite subcover. What's special is that *all* open covers have a finite subcover (compactness).

Comment: @HennoBrandsma What an amazing elucidation! Can't thank you enough.

Comment: @vicky glad it helped you a bit.

Answer (score 2):

Every subset of $\Bbb R$ (or really of any topological space with sufficiently many open sets) has finite open covers and infinite open covers. What *compact* subsets *specifically lack* (in the case of $\Bbb R$, they are the closed and bounded subsets) is *an open cover such that no finite subfamily of it is a cover*. The fact that in $\Bbb R^n$ the compact subsets are exactly the closed and bounded sets is known as Heine-Borel theorem.